# Select an id where the foreign key is null

Tags: sql-server

how to select an auction id from a table where in  another table the auction id is null please,is there any way i have try is null but not working can someone help please? Hope can get an answer

```
SELECT        Auction.AuctionID
FROM            Item 
               INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID 
               INNER JOIN BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID
WHERE        (Auction.Status = 'Valid') AND (BID.AuctionID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: And how are those Auction tables related to each other?

Comment: one auction can have one or more bid

Comment: And you are looking for bids with null auction ids?

Comment: Are you looking for auctions ids where there are no bids made?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find auctions where no bids are made

```
SELECT        Auction.AuctionID -- other columns 
FROM            Item 
               INNER JOIN Auction ON Item.ItemID = Auction.ItemID 
               Left outer JOIN BID ON Auction.AuctionID = BID.AuctionID
WHERE        (Auction.Status = 'Valid') and bid.auctionid is null
Group by auction.auctionid
Having count(bid.auctionid) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using inner join between Auction and Bid tables. Use Left Join instead.

Comment: can i have an example please

Comment: There are plenty of examples on web. Just read up for Left join on MSDN or wherever you prefer.